# inference variable T has incompatible bounds Error

Tags: java, arraylist, generic-method

```
ArrayList<ShipDetail> detailArray = new ArrayList<ShipDetail>(Arrays.asList(shipDetail));
Sorter.QuickSort( detailArray );
```

And this is my Sorter class in which I was trying to do Implement some algorithms.

```
public class Sorter
{
   public static<T extends Comparable<T>> void QuickSort(AbstractList<T> collection )
   {
        quickSort(collection,0,collection.size()-1);
   }

}
```

But while compiling i am getting the following error :

required: AbstractList
  found: ArrayList
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: ShipDetail
    upper bounds: Comparable
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable declared in method QuickSort(AbstractList)

Comment: Is `ShipDetail` comparable to itself? This is required (note `<T extends Comparable<T>>`)

Comment: u mean if I have override compare to method if so Yes

Comment: Show the class declaration of `ShipDetail`.

Comment: Please post the signature of that class (what it implements and extends)

Comment: this is signature of my ship class
: public class ShipDetail implements Comparator<ShipDetail>

Comment: Comparator != Comparable

Comment: It should implement `Comparable`, not `Comparator`.

Comment: To be more precise Comparators are objects-algorithms which provide service of comparison of other objects, while Comparables are objects which themselves allow comparing them to other kind of objects.

Answer (score 6):

`ShipDetail` is not comparable to itself. The bound here:

`<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Also applies to the type variable `T` in the argument, which is inferred as `ShipDetail`.

`ShipDetail` should be defined as follows:

```
class ShipDetail implements Comparable<ShipDetail> { ...
```

And not:

```
class ShipDetail implements Comparator<ShipDetail> { ...
```

`Comparator`s are objects-algorithms which provide service of comparison of other objects, while `Comparable`s are objects which themselves allow comparing them to other kind of objects.

Comment: Thanks now I understood difference of using Comparator and Comparable.

Comment: @Anny cool!you can mark the answer with the green tick if you think it answers your question fully.